# How to find the difference between a date and an other (if the second is not exactly into the dataFrame)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have been stucked with this problem sice few days... I don't know how to solve it. 
I have a dataframe with in Index some dates. I want to select a window equal to a number of days, lets say 5 days for example. I want to have back a dataFrame with my initial dates in index and in the first column the difference of days between each dates in index and the 5 days window closest day in the past.

Lets set up an example.

```
[In] Mydates
[Out] 
2017-04-04   
2017-04-03    
2017-03-31    
2017-03-30   
2017-03-29   
2017-03-28   
2017-03-27   
2017-03-24  
2017-03-23     
2017-03-21
```

I want back

```
func(window = 5)
    return MyNewdates
[out]         First column
2017-04-04   -5 [diff between 2017-04-04 and 5 days before or closest date in dataset from 5 days before (here 2017-03-30 ), so difference is 0 - 5 =] -5 

2017-04-03   -5  [diff between 2017-04-03 and 5 days before or closest date in dataset from 5 days before (here 2017-03-29), so difference is 0 - 5 =] -5 
2017-03-31    
2017-03-30   -6  [here, there is no 2017-03-25 (5 days before) so the closest date from my window is 2017-03-24 (6 days before), so the difference is 0 - 6 =] -6 

2017-03-29   -5  [diff between 2017-03-29 and 5 days before or closest date in dataset from 5 days before (here 2017-03-24), so difference is 0 - 5 =] -5 
2017-03-28   -5  [diff between 2017-03-29 and 5 days before or closest date in dataset from 5 days before (here 2017-03-23 ), so difference is 0 - 5 =] -5 
2017-03-27   -4  [diff between 2017-03-27 and 5 days before or closest date in dataset from 5 days before (here 2017-03-23 ), so difference is 0 - 4 =] -4
2017-03-24  NAN 
2017-03-23  NAN    
2017-03-21  NAN
```

etc...

To do so, I transformed all my dates in days. Is there any other ways? I want that it gives me back the days differences.

I hope it is clear, please let me know if you have any questions!

Thank you!!

Comment: Can you edit your question with the full desired output as it's unclear what you want to show for the last 4 dates for example

Comment: @EdChum , done, thank you again for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC then following works as desired:

```
In [141]:
import io
import pandas as pd
# read in data
t="""Dates
2017-04-04   
2017-04-03    
2017-03-31    
2017-03-30   
2017-03-29   
2017-03-28   
2017-03-27   
2017-03-24  
2017-03-23   
2017-03-22   
2017-03-21  """
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), delim_whitespace=True, parse_dates=[0], index_col=[0])
# define a window func
def func(x, window):
    prev = x - pd.DateOffset(window)
    if df.index.isin([prev]).any() == True:
        return -window
    elif (prev < df.index).all():
        return np.NaN
    else:
        diff = (df.index - prev).to_series().abs() 
        diff_idx = diff.index.get_loc(diff.argmin())
        return - ((x - (x - df.iloc[diff_idx]).name).days)

df.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: func(x, 5))
Out[141]:

Dates
2017-04-04   -5.0
2017-04-03   -5.0
2017-03-31   -4.0
2017-03-30   -6.0
2017-03-29   -5.0
2017-03-28   -5.0
2017-03-27   -5.0
2017-03-24    NaN
2017-03-23    NaN
2017-03-22    NaN
2017-03-21    NaN
Name: Dates, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hi  @EdChum , Thank you very much for you help. May I ask you how have you created the df and how can I make it not as a function? 
To be clear, what is x for you? My serie of dates?
My ultimate goal is to return ne number of days difference between what you created and the initial dates. Sometime it will be exactly 5 days, sometime it will be 6 or 7 or 8 because there is not the exact date for 5 days.

Comment: The lambda here will be each date as it's being passed via the `lambda`, sorry I should change `pd.DateOffset(5)` to `pd.DateOffset(window)` to make it more generic, will update

Comment: No problem, I understand that part. I just don't understand how you define your ' df ' and how I can include it in a code without defining it as a function. I assume that your ' x ' is actually Mydates.index, right?

Comment: I created a df with a single column called `Dates`, you didn't provide any raw data or code to create your df/series so whether the data is the index/column in a Series or DF shouldn't matter, you just need to tweak the code to suit your situation, you need to edit your question with clearer explanation

Comment: Could you check the latest update which I think now does what you want

Comment: Thank you very much, thats exactly what I am looking for!! 
2 last things. The line 
`df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), delim_whitespace=True, parse_dates=[0], index_col=[0])` do not work, it gives back `TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str`
Then, is x is the dates? 

Thank you again!

Comment: Ignore that line, that is just for me to read in your data using your text so it converts that multi-line string into a file object. If my answer resolved your question, remember to accept it, there will be an empty tick mark at the top left of my answer. This is so the question doesn't remain as unanswered

Comment: for more precision, can you tell me exactly to what should correspond the variable ' x ' and the dataFrame ' df ' ?

Comment: `x` here will be row and `df` is just dataframe

Comment: Last question for you @EdChum . What if I want constantly the closest date BELOW my window, meaning, If my window is '5' days, I dont want the func to give me back the -4 but always minimum -5, -6 etc... so if its a -4, it looks for the next closest date from my window which can be -7 for example. I am strugling with that...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution a thought about:

```
def date_dif(x, dates, window):

    try:
        return (x - dates[dates <= x - pd.DateOffset(window)][0]).days
    except:
        return None
```

Then you can use lambda:

```
df['time_dif'] = df.index.map(lambda x: date_dif(x, df.index, 5))
```

For more info I created my df as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

start_date = dt.datetime(2017,3,21)
end_date = dt.datetime(2017,4,4)

delta = end_date - start_date

dates = [start_date + dt.timedelta(days=i) for i in range(delta.days +1)]


df = pd.DataFrame(index=dates)
df.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

Hope this helps.